# Is length function of array working in statement of for loop?

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop

I am checking users inputs to control white space entry. Also string arrays are declared on global class like that,

```
public static String[] sortAnswer;
```

but application explodes on this code at beginning of for loop row. it has stopped on the for statement.
`for(int i=0; (i < Global.sortAnswer.length );i++)`  when I add brackets like that `.length()` warns with red mark. I am sure that it should be `.length` 
I have two questions mainly
1-) Initializing string array is wrong ?
2-) Global.sortAnswer.length is not working about counting of array length ?

```
btnQuestionSortSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    edSortQuestion.setText(Global.firstLetterUpper(edSortQuestion.getText().toString()));
    boolean sortCntrol=false;
    for(int i=0; (i < Global.sortAnswer.length );i++)
    {
        if (Global.sortAnswer[i].toString().equals("")||Global.sortAnswer[i].toString()==""||Global.sortAnswer[i].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            sortCntrol=true;
        }
    }


    if(edSortQuestion.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        showMessage(con, getResources().getString(R.string.QuestionSort_fillQuestion), -140,"yellow");
    }
    else if(sortCntrol)
    {
        showMessage(con, getResources().getString(R.string.Question_Empty), -140,"yellow");
    }
```

*Thank you,
Sincerely*

Comment: `but application explodes` is not a good description of the problem. Please provide as much detail as possible about what is going wrong ESPECIALLY if there's an error/exception/stack trace you aren't sharing. Also, are you sure that should `length` and not `length()`? That's a method, not a property.

Comment: Please provide your exception and stack trace

Comment: what and where is your problem?

Comment: it has stopped on the for statement.  
for(int i=0; (i < Global.sortAnswer.length );i++) 
I have two questions mainly
1-) Initializing string array is wrong ?
2-) Global.sortAnswer.length is not working about counting of array length ?

Comment: when I add brackets like that `.length()` warns with red mark. I am sure that it should be `.length`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know if we don't know the exception that it throws.

First suggestions would be to check if:

- `sortAnswer` is `null`
- one or more of the items in `sortAnswers` are `null`

Comment: Does not  `.length() `  count length of null string array ?

Comment: No @OrGor it does not, calling `.length` on a `null` array a `NullPointerException` is thrown.